# Column row value shows blank after adding default value to column of Data Table in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

[image]

if i add new rows after adding default column value then it shows value , but i want to avoid this if i add then i need to remove this rows , is there any way to handle this

Why column hack shows blank value after adding default value to it?

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("HackTable");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Id"); 
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Name"); 
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Address"); 
myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Rahul", "Parel"); 
myDataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Ramesh", "Dadar"); 
myDataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Ravi", "Andheri"); 
DataSet dsT = new DataSet(); 
dsT.Tables.Add(myDataTable); 
dsT.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Hack").DefaultValue = 9999;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Data.DataColumn newColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn("Hack", typeof(System.Int32));
newColumn.DefaultValue =9999;
dsT.Tables[0].Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

Set default value  for the column and then add to datatable

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("HackTable");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Id"); 
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Name"); 
myDataTable.Columns.Add("Address");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("newColumn");
myDataTable.Columns["newColumn"].DefaultValue = "default";
myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Rahul", "Parel"); 
myDataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Ramesh", "Dadar"); 
myDataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Ravi", "Andheri");

DataSet dsT = new DataSet(); 
dsT.Tables.Add(myDataTable);
```

You have to set default value to column before you insert data.

Comment: i am adding 3 DataTable to DataSet , after that for each table i have to add  column which having default value , here i dont want to add any row bcz data table is coming with all data .

Comment: i know that if i add new rows after adding default column value then it shows value , but i want to avoid this if i add then i need to remove this rows , is there any way to handle this

Comment: According to your question and piece of code you shared, my answer give's you clue how to do that. Then you are saying that `DataTable` comes with data. Next time be more precise.

Comment: sorry for that but i just shown the simple example in my code i am dealing with multiple tables which i have to add in data set ,as good practice of posting code here i have added rows and column manualy

Comment: If `DataTable` comes with data, can't you just add new column before assigning to `DataGridView.DataSource`?

Comment: My bad, it won't help :(

Comment: thanks , but i failed to explain the question that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet dsT = new DataSet();
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable("HackTable");
        dsT.Tables.Add(myDataTable);
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Address");
        dsT.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Hack").DefaultValue = "9999"; //<-here
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Rahul", "Parel");
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Ramesh", "Dadar");
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Ravi", "Andheri");
```

Comment: Isn't that just a copy of Lemur's answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Sample");
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Add");
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "abc", "hyd");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn("Hack", typeof(System.String));
        newColumn.DefaultValue = "Your Default value";
        dt.Columns.Add(newColumn);

        string str = ""; 
    }
```

[See snap: IDE Visual Studio DataSet Visualizer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtc9C.png)